Newly created Next.js app giving error URL.canParse is not a function
I have created Next.js app by the command npx create-next-app@latest after running it npm run dev, I am getting below error.

Uncaught TypeError: URL.canParse is not a function
at getSocketUrl (webpack-internal:///(:3001/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/helpers/get-socket-url.js:23:13)

The app is created with Next.js version 14.2.11
I have tried to fix it by following suggestions provided by ChatGpt with no success. Tried below solutions
npm update next react react-dom
Clear Cache - rm -rf .next
Restart server - npm run dev

Were you running Electron? I got the same error if running in Electron, but work if running in Chrome.

@LawrenceZeng same here, got the error only when running with Electron

Downgrading nextjs version to 14.2.10 works.

A similiar issue suggest checking/updating your node-version as well as upgrading @types/node. This might work for you, too.
According to Node.js URL.canParse was added in: v19.9.0, v18.17.0.
You can run node -v in your terminal to check your current Node version.

node version is 22.2.0

downgrade nextjs version from "next": "14.2.11" to "next": "14.2.10" and "eslint-config-next": "14.2.11" to "eslint-config-next": "14.2.11" downgrading to stable nextjs version works whenever installing a new nextjs project

I was having this issue only with Safari. Chrome and Opera GX worked just fine.
Node version I was using was v20.13.0. I tried upgrading to Node version to v22.9.0, and it didn't work.
Next.js version I was using was 14.2.11. In the end, downgrading next version to 14.2.10 worked.
There was no need to touch eslint-config-next, which I left at 14.2.11 in my package.json.

Agreed, downgrading to Next.js 14.2.10 resolves the issue. Hopefully, this will be addressed in the latest version of Next.js soon.

The latest version fix the issue:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v14.2.13

feat: add polyfill of URL.canParse for browser compatibility (#70228)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

vercel has fixed this issue in next 14.2.13.
So, you can upgrade your current version by editing "next" dependency version in your package.json file:
from:
"dependencies": {
//other packages
"next": "14.2.11"
}

to:
"dependencies": {
//other packages
"next": "14.2.13"
}

and then run the command:
npm update next

then run your app again.
I hope this helpful

Please update Next to the latest version.
Also, don't forget to update your web browser as well.

i have it also on the latest version, I guess its related to the browser
